# Missing pages in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, missing-features

When I click on "install all missing woocommerce pages" in System status it gives me an ERROR: options page not found.
https://www.freshmorrow.com/wp-admin/options.php

Answer (score 0):

That url (/wp-admin/options.php) isn't going to do much without a login.

Can you ftp into your directory and check if they are there?

It should be somewhere like:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce
```

You also could delete the plugin and reinstall it?

Edit: didn't read close enough.

make sure the file /wp-admin/options.php exists as well